# How to Show the Playing Video on CustomeSurfaceview on Target Recognized in Wikitutde Android Native APi?

Tags: android, sdk, surfaceview, augmented-reality, wikitude

I wanted to play a video on Costume Surface View and it is done but video is not showing on Costume Surface View .I am Using Wikitude SDK .
And Here Is my Code........

Here i am setting my  UI...

```
@Override
    public void onRenderExtensionCreated(final RenderExtension renderExtension_) {
        _glRenderer = new GLRenderer(renderExtension_);
        _customSurfaceView = new CustomSurfaceView(getApplicationContext(), _glRenderer);
        _driver = new Driver(_customSurfaceView, 30);
        //setContentView(_customSurfaceView);
        FrameLayout viewHolder = new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext());
        viewHolder.addView(_customSurfaceView);
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_barcode_plugin,viewHolder,false);
        viewHolder.addView(view);
        setContentView(viewHolder);
    }
```

And on target Recognized i am trying to do like this..

```
@Override
    public void onTargetRecognized(final Tracker tracker_, final String targetName_) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Thread Name is" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
                android.widget.MediaController mediaController = new android.widget.MediaController(BarcodePluginActivity.this);
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.javavideotutorial;
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(fileName);
                videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Video is playing But it is Not showing on Surface of Camera. When in onTargetRecognized method i am Doing The costume surface view Invisible/Gone the video is showing but I want it to show on Camera Preview ...How to Overcome This Problem??? Please help me.. I am using Wikitude SDK, Android Native Api and running code on Android Studio.
And Here is my Layout...

And Here is my Layout..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:id="@+id/lin">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/barcode_plugin_info_field"
        android:editable="false"
        android:background="@color/wikitude_orange_light"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/barcode_hint"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        />
    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am playing Video On Video View .And don't bother about Edit Text please.

Answer (score 1):

This is because both the CustomSurfaceView and your VideoView are SurfaceViews. A SurfaceView is a special type of view, which does not behave like any other view.

Right now your VideoView get's rendered below the CustomSurfaceView. When adding the view in the "onRenderExtensionCreated()" method add the following call:

```
videoView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
```